# Run Test Play! Framework - DataSource user is null

Tags: java, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hello I am trying run a simple test in a web app using Play! Framework, but I got a error:

```
[info] RouteTest
[error] Test RouteTest.testRouteActivityIndex failed: DataSource user is null?
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool.<init>(DataSourcePool.java:198)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceManager.getDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:210)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceGlobalManager.getDataSource(DataSourceGlobalManager.java:63)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultServerFactory.java:427)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.setDataSource(DefaultServerFactory.java:388)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:168)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:125)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:64)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getWithCreate(Ebean.java:237)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.get(Ebean.java:224)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.access$200(Ebean.java:159)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.getServer(Ebean.java:288)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.Model$Finder.server(Model.java:216)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.Model$Finder.all(Model.java:230)
[error]     at models.Activity.all(Activity.java:29)
[error]     at controllers.Application.activities(Application.java:18)
[error]     at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:60)
[error]     at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:60)
[error]     at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$4$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:1086)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:33)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:74)
[error]     at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$4$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:1085)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.invokeHandler(Helpers.java:34)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.routeAndCall(Helpers.java:246)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.routeAndCall(Helpers.java:231)
[error]     at RouteTest.testRouteActivityIndex(RouteTest.java:14)
[error]     ...
[info] x RouteTest.testRouteActivityIndex
```

The code of test is:

```
    @Test
public void testRouteActivityIndex(){
    Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/activities"));
    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
```

I tried researching the error, but did not find anything very useful for this case, even the site's play!. someone has gone through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/activities` action probably make some calls to the DB.

So you should make your test in a running fake application as explained in the "Running in a fake application" section of this documentation: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaTest

And don't forget to import the static Helper:

```
import static play.test.Helpers.*;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw this approach in the site BUT for some strange reason I ignore it . Sorry . Thanks again.